Class not found when trying to archive xcode project
I have an xcode project that builds and runs, but get errors when I try to archive it. I looked at other posts with this problem but none had this particular error. Can someone explain what the code in red means?

Here's my code for token, which is in the same folder as everything else.
struct Token: Codable {
    
var id = UUID()
var value: String
var user: UserID

    init(value: String, user: UserID){
    self.value = value
    self.user = user
    }
    
    static let archiveURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("tokens").appendingPathExtension("plist")
    
    static func saveToFile(tokenList: [Token]) {
        let propertyListEncoder = PropertyListEncoder()
        let encodedToDoList = try? propertyListEncoder.encode(tokenList)
        try? encodedToDoList?.write(to: Token.archiveURL, options: .noFileProtection)
    }
    
    static func loadFromFile() -> [Token] {
        let propertyListDecoder = PropertyListDecoder()
        if let retrievedTokenData = try? Data(contentsOf: Token.archiveURL), let decodedTokenList = try? propertyListDecoder.decode(Array<Token>.self, from: retrievedTokenData) {
            
            return decodedTokenList
        } else {
            return []
        }
    }
}

Based on this post:
Classes not found when archiving SwiftUI app
I went ahead and made sure Build Configuration is set to Release, with no change in the result.

Is Token defined inside #if DEBUG or something like that? Also, are you sure it's added to the target you're building?

Token is not inside an #if DEGUB. I've edited the post to include my Token class code. I believe it's added to the target as it's in the same folder as everything else, but maybe there's more to this than I understand.

You need to look in the right column (the inspector) in Xcode or in the Build Phases of your target and make sure that file is included. Being in the same folder is inconsequential.

Okay thanks for that explanation, I checked and it is added to the target I'm building.

The Token file was not in the same directory as the rest of the files. After moving Token to the same directory I am able to archive.
